# Google Cloud Messaging missing lib in app engine

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app for android with endpoints in the server side and I need to use GCM to push notifications. If I run localy it's all fine, I don't have any errors. But when I deploy the project on app engine and I sent a notification I have this error

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender
```

I added gcm-server.jar correctly to the build path, proof is I can run locally without errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `gcm-server.jar` file to the Build Path and that helps out locally when trying to compile, build and run locally.

When deploying to the App Engine environment, please put your additional JAR files in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder also. Deploy it after that.